# Finding index/period of a semigroup element

Tags: nt.number-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

The *index* and *period* of a finite monogenic semigroup $\langle x\rangle$ are the smallest numbers $i$ and $p$, respectively, satisfying $x^{i+p}=x^p$. The question is:

***Is there an algorithm to find the index/period of a finite monogenic semigroup of size $n$ in $o(n)$ (or $O(n^\epsilon)$ with $\epsilon<1$) steps?***

Note: the number $n$ is assumed to be unknown, otherwise the  problem is trivial.

Comment: How is the weekend element given?

Comment: If you mean $x$, it can be an square matrix over a finite field (of possibly large dimensions).

Comment: Is the generator $x$ of the monogenic semigroup known? And what is the input of a desired algorithm? The multiplication table of the monogenic semigroup?

Comment: @Taras Banakh Yes, for instance a square matrix (of possibly large size).

Comment: @M.FarrokhiD.G. So, just to input data, you will need $O(n^2)$ memory. The input yields the value of $n=i+p$. After that you would like to make $o(n)$ operations and obtain the values of the index and period? Right?

Comment: @Taras Banack I think there is something wrong with your notation $n$. Memory is not important here and we will not save the whole semigroup but the generator $x$. What is important is the number of operations and the smallest values of $i$ and $p$.

Comment: @M.FarrokhiD.G. Aha, so we know the generator $x$ and then the simplest algorithm of complexity $O(n)$ is just to calculate the powers $x^k$ till we find the first repetition $x^k=x^i$ for some $i$? Now I believe that there can be an algorithm of complexity $O(\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: @Taras Banack The problem is well explained here [Cycle detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection).

Comment: @M.FarrokhiD.G. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Won't Pollard's rho method give you a collision $x^k=x^\ell$ with $k>\ell$ in time roughly $O(\sqrt{n})$ (and $O(1)$ storage). From there you should be able to work back to the index and period.

Comment: I think technically it is Floyd's cycle finding method, but Pollard may have enhanced it to work for this case. (Version 2: Now I think Brent or Gosper may have modified it.) Gerhard "Attribution Where Attribution Is Due" Paseman, 2017.07.21.